# Deplyoment Issue in Migrating from Primefaces 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish, netbeans-8

I was using primefaces 3.5 in my project and now have updated to 4.0 but its failing to deploy on Glassfish after upgrading and resulting in the following error:

```
Severe:   Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.Exception:
No Function Found on type: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils with
signature: java.lang.String resolveWidgetVar(java.lang.String)
```

I have removed the 3.5 version JAR and placed the new one in the project library, but still failing to deploy with the mentioned error given.

I'm using:

- Glassfish: 4.1,
- Netbeans 8.0.1

Comment: Do a clean and build. Also remove the old library from glassFish/lib and from the project libraries (right click -> properties - > libraries).

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I have cleaned and built, removed libraries from project libraries and still can't deploy. Where do I locate the old library in glassfish/lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear glassfish cache because old primefaces library which referred in the class path of your app server.

1. Stop the glassfish server.
2. Delete the content of the `osgi-cache`, by removing the `felix` directory in your domain. This is usually found in `glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache`